# How to disable Editor (DevDemon) for Category Descriptions

Tags: categories, devdemon, editor

I want to completely disable Editor for my Category Descriptions and have it revert back to the simple text area field that ships with EE.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is "disable" the Editor Extension. That is the only thing the extension does!

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. It was hard to tell what to do as the documentation is a little "sparse"